# How to access vs2010's BuildEngine from an AddIn?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, add-in

Is it possible to access Visual Studios BuildEngine from an AddIn?
I want to start a build target whenever a file with a specifice extension is safed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this answer: [run a custom msbuild target from VisualStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124731/run-a-custom-msbuild-target-from-visualstudio/5124970#5124970)

You'll just need to wire into a different event handler, but otherwise the details are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Part of my problem was to log error messages to the ErrorList. It seems there is no other possibility as implementing a simple Logger. But your tip helped me going that way.