# Run other than the DefaultTarget for a project configuration under Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuild-task, csproj, msbuild-target

I've a MSBuild target in my csproj to copy files and folders of my web application to a target path after build.

```
<Target Name="PublishToFileSystem" DependsOnTargets="PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder">
...
```

If I call MSBuild via command line with the target "PublishToFileSystem" everything works fine.

But now I want to "use" this target also for a special configuration in Visual Studio (like Release, Debug, ...).

How can I assign a configuration to another target than the DefaultTarget "Build" set in the project with DefaultTargets:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Thanks, Konrad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use AfterBuild target instead of PublishToFileSystem:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder">
```

or check [Overriding Predefined Targets on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Using the DependsOnTargets in the AfterBuild-Target, I get the error of a circular dependcy in AfterBuild.

Comment: PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder target depends on AfterBuild target?

Comment: Maybe some sub-task in PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder is a build that again calls AfterBuild.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this for a specific solution configuration and you're suffering from ciruclar dependencies as I was, the easiest thing I could come up with is writing your own Target to use as default target. That target starts other targets based on a condition on the configuration.

```
<Target Name="CustomBuild">
  <CallTarget Targets="SignAndroidPackage" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'UITest'"/>
  <CallTarget Targets="Build" Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'UITest'"/>
</Target>
```

And then simply change the Default target at the top of the project definition to that CustomBuild target.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="CustomBuild" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that might suit your need:  [run a custom msbuild target from VisualStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124731/run-a-custom-msbuild-target-from-visualstudio)

(this is trick #78 in the book [MSBuild Trickery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/061550907X))

Comment: Hmmm ... hoped I could define a configuration like "ReleaseAndDeploy" that I can also use as configuration on TFS-Build-Server without any additional modifications. AddOns in my VS-Tools seem not to be a clear solution. Couldn't I define another target than the DefaultTarget for only one of my configurations?

Comment: Sure, Configurations *can* be used that way.  Just wire targets into the Build and make use of Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'ReleaseAndDeploy'".  I never use Configurations like that though.  My preference is to drive builds from a command line and lately lots of Powershell.  For me, the IDE is nice UI, but not much help with SDLC, since everything is tied to the solution and solutions are a pretty lame basis for, well, anything really.