# Adding empty platform configuration to MSBuild

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

As part of a test process, I'm trying to create an empty MSBuild Platform Target for MVS 2010 whose only job is to call a batch file when I click "build". I want to completely ignore the build and link process of the c++ files, just call a batch file (perhaps with the post-build events?).

So far I've duplicated the Win32 platform at \MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms and named it "TestPlatform", and started hacking away at it and managed to disable the build step, but it, quite reasonably, fails during the link step when it cant find my SampleProject.o file that the build file did not generate.

I've ordered the book "Inside the Microsoft Build Engine: Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build" book by Hashimi and Bartholomew, but while it gets here I would appreciate if anyone has any words of wisdom on the subject. Specifically:

1 - How do I bypass the link step.

2 - How do I add a custom step to call a DoSomething.bat file instead

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my particular case, I found that adding a copy of the C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32 platform (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\TestPlatform) and adding the TestPlatform to my project configuration was enough to bring out the TestPlatform tab in the Configuration Manager dropdown menu.

To make it not compile or link anything but still run postbuild events the easiest way is to select in project properties:
Configuration Properties / General / Configuration Type : Utility
This seems to bypass all building steps but does call the postbuild events, where I simply put a call to a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you are proposing, but a different way of achieving some of the same results is found here:  [run a custom msbuild target from VisualStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124731/run-a-custom-msbuild-target-from-visualstudio/5124970#5124970)

That shows how to wire up a command in the IDE to call a custom target in your project.  So you could wire up an IDE command to call your RunThisBatchFile target in the current project.

Alternatively, you could override the rogue targets with a condition, something like:

```
<Target Name="Link" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'TestPlatform'">
   ...
```

You may need to find a bunch of these and I'm not sure if it is 100% possible to get around the InitialTargets that may be defined for a C++ project file.

This is all covered in "[MSBuild Trickery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/061550907X)"

Comment: Thank you for the info. I found a workaround for my particular case but your input helped quite a bit.